# How to design a repository writing to pub/sub and reading from database in clean architecture

Tags: asynchronous, repository-pattern, cqrs, clean-architecture

I want to design my application which requires writing asynchronously through pub/sub and reading synchronously from the database. How do you implement this in clean architecture? There's a separate process reading from the pub/sub and writing to the database.

I'm thinking of a design like this; however, I wasn't sure if it's a good design for one repository to be implemented using separate persistent infrastructure for reading and writing.

```
  Repository   |     Controller   |    Infrastructure
my repository ---> my controller ---> (write) pub/sub
                                  \-> (read)  database
```

An alternative could be CQRS, but in my case, I use the same model for reading and writing, so I think it's better to use a single model.

Background:
Writes to my application are very elastic, while reads are consistent. So I avoid getting my service overloaded by writing asynchronously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It the same as with any other clean architecture application.

```
+------------+  ||  +----------+      +------------+
| Controller | ---> | Use Case | ---> | Repository |
+------------+  ||  +-----------      +------------+
                ||                    | save()     |
                ||                    | find()     |
                ||                    +------------+
                ||                          ^
============================================|==========                               
                                            |
                                      +------------+
                                      |  RepoImpl  |
                                      +------------+
                                      | save()     | ---> write to pub/sub
                                      | find()     | ---> read from db
                                      +------------+
```

Maybe you split up the repository writes and reads into different interfaces, because you might have a use case that only reads and another that only writes.
I usually apply the interface segregation principle and define use case specific interfaces.